# Moving common code into `subprojects {}` block breaks build

Tags: maven, gradle, artifacts, multi-project

I have a multi-project (multiple java subprojects) in Grade and I plan to upload it to a maven repository (currently a local one) including the `sources` and `javadoc` artifacts. I simply add the following code to each subproject and then `maven install` does the job:

```
apply plugin: 'maven'

task sourcesJar(type: Jar, dependsOn:classes) {
        from sourceSets.main.allSource 
        classifier = 'sources' 
} 
task javadocJar(type: Jar, dependsOn:javadoc) {
        from javadoc.destinationDir 
        classifier = 'javadoc' 
}
artifacts { 
        archives jar
        archives sourcesJar 
        archives javadocJar 
}
```

Now its not that nice to have the same code in 10 subprojects, so I decided I will move this code into the `subprojects { ... }` configuration of the *parent* project. However, now it does not work anymore: Only empty sources and javadoc jars are built, the normal jar is ignored, and `maven install` does not copy the files anymore to the local maven repository. How to do this right?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A parent project's build script gets evaluated before its subprojects' build scripts. When you lift some code to a parent project's build script, you'll have to make sure that the evaluation order stays intact, i.e. that the lifted code doesn't eagerly read properties that are only set by a subproject's build script. For example, if `javadoc.destinationDir` is set by a subproject's build script, you'll either have to lift that code too, or defer evaluation of the `from javadoc.destinationDir` expression in the parent build script.

There are several techniques for deferring evaluation. Some properties (like an archive task's `from` and `into`) accept a closure; hence you can simply do `from { javadoc.destinationDir }`. Another option is to use hooks like `gradle.projectsEvaluated {}`, `project.afterEvaluate {}`, or `task.doFirst {}`. The first step in deciding which technique to use is to look up the property in question in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).

Without seeing more of your build scripts, my best guess is that your particular problems are related to not lifting `apply plugin: "java"` into the parent build script's `subprojects {}` block.

An alternative to configuration injection (e.g. via `subprojects {}`) is to put common code into a separate build script, and have project build scripts include that code with `apply from:`. In some cases, this is an easier way to (selectively) share code than configuration injection. Often, the two approaches are used together.

Comment: Hi Peter, thanks, moving the `apply plugin: 'java'` into the `subprojects` solved the problem!